# Как вставить в таблицу несколько записей с одинаковыми полями без дублирования?

Tags: mysql

Возможно ли в MySQL сгруппировать данные для вставки по полям, если они одинаковые? Например:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `type`, `value`) 
VALUES
(1, 'specific_type', 'specific_value'),
(2, 'specific_type', 'specific_value'),
(4, 'specific_type', 'specific_value_2')...
```

Есть ли запись запроса, где можно указать список id, тип и значение для всех этих id и не дублировать для каждой вставки `type` и `value`?

Comment: А "список id" в каком виде ? Если текстом через запятую, то `select group_concat(id), type, value from table group by type, value`

Comment: @Mike да, есть список id текстом через запятую (можно и в другом виде). Необходимо вставить большое количество записей, у которых разные id, но одинаковые остальные поля.
Данные не лежат в других таблицах, чтобы их забрать SELECT'ом, нужно сформировать запрос руками.

Comment: Преобразуйте список значений в набор записей. Используйте `INSERT .. SELECT`, общие значения - как литералы. Точная версия MySQL - какая?

Comment: @Akina MySQL 5.7.9

Comment: Плохо. Рекурсивные СТЕ недоступны, придётся генерировать набор записей.